# что не так с математическим простым уравнением?

Tags: php

```
$this->currency = '28' //строка я так понимаю так как выбирается из select
$price = '9.35'; тоже скорей всего строка так как без (float) писало ошибки про numeric
$this->markup = '100' //строка я так понимаю так как выбирается из select
//уравнение

$total_price = ($this->currency * (float)$price) + ($this->currency * (float)$price) * $this->markup / 100;
return (int)$total_price; //на выходе хотел получить целое число
вывело 504

а если посчитать на калькуляторе:
(28 * 9,35 )+ (28 * 9,35 )* 100/100 = 523,6 ну если округлить по int получитя же 523 а не 504
```

Comment: Вы сначала строки приведите к числам, а потом делайте вычисления. Запятые на точки можете заменить с помощью str_replace

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать сменить локаль:
`setlocale( LC_NUMERIC, 'en_GB' );`

Если расчет нужен точный испольчуйте BCMath:
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.bc.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$currency = '28';
$price = '9,35';
$markup = '100';

$price = str_replace(',', '.', $price);

$total_price = ($currency * (float)$price) + ($currency * (float)$price) * $markup / 100;
echo floor($total_price);
```

Проблема в том, что в price стоит запятая. Когда делаешь float() она просто отбрасывается и price = 9. Надо ее изменить на точку, делаем это с помощью str_replace.

В конце floor() округляет число на цело в меньшую сторону.

Comment: floor -- это если мы покупаем

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov в вопросе ТС ожидал округление в меньшую сторону. Так что вот оно

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]